# Magento 2.3.0 upgrade to 2.3.4, Admin not showing version update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.4

I am updating my production site from 2.3.0 to 2.3.4. Updating goes smoothly with no errors at all.
Yet my backend(adminhtml) is not updated!!

It still shows the old number (2.3.0) in the bottom right.
Using `php bin/magento -v` on the cli I get the right version! 2.3.4

So I know that it seems to be on version 2.3.4, because the Export Products bug I was updating to fix is fixed!
Also I was running ElasticSearch 5, and 2.3.4 isn't compatible so it stopped working. Yet when I go try to change the catalog search ElasticSearch 6 or 7 are not options!!

First I updated via composer. I'll list the commands, but I had no errors.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.4 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

adminhtml seems to deploy just fine. I've tried clearing all caches. Applying the -area admin ti deploy.
I also tried installing via FTP. I downloaded the full version of 2.3.4 and uploaded it and ran setup:update. No luck.
I feel like I'm missing something really small.
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image: Composer Version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update. Super simple solution.
Deleted my Vendor folder and then reran `composer update`

I was pretty sure I already did this once, but hey it worked after.

Answer (score 0):

I might be an issue for Magento. Flush all Magento cache Or

Check `composer.json` at Magento root directly. Might be `composer.json` still it version is  `2.3.0`. You need to changes that version manually to   `2.3.4` or check JSON file at **var** folder's JSON files which are relater Magento corn.

Comment: Checked 'composer.json' shows '2.3.4'. I have cleared every cache. Even deleting all files and running setup:static-content:deploy. 
Cache makes the most sense but I've checked everything. Really baffled on this one.